# c++ map/unordered_map, will "insert" change the iterator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

How to understand the sentence in cpprefference in section map/insert which is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> If the insertion is successful, pointers and references to the
> element obtained while it is held in the node handle are invalidated,
> and pointers and references obtained to that element before it was
> extracted become valid.

Comment: That comment applies to the overloads involving `node_type`. Note that it doesn't mention iterators, only pointers and references. As the sentence just before it says, "no iterators or references are invalidated." (Also note that this does not imply that concurrent modification is safe.)

Comment: There are no thread safety guarantees in this STL, so if you access the same container at the same time from different threads the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Please, ask only one question per question.

Comment: I believe it refers to insertion of an extracted element. It doesn't cause any invalidation of any iterators or references. However, iterating over iterators is a different thing and it imposes memory races when done from different threads when erase/insert/extract operations are used.

Comment: @gerum *There are no thread safety guarantees in this STL* - That's not true: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety

Comment: @DanielLangr sorry for this time~

Comment: @f1msch: if you edit this down to one question and post the others as separate questions (first checking whether they already exist), you're more likely to get answers.

Comment: See also: "[Using std::map::extract to modify key](//stackoverflow.com/q/53196275/90527)"

Answer (score 1):

The quoted section applies when `insert` is called on a [node handle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle), which are [extracted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) from containers. Importantly, these were previously elements of a container, but were removed. Also relevant is this section from `map::extract`:

> Extracting a node invalidates only the iterators to the extracted element. Pointers and references to the extracted element remain valid, but cannot be used while element is owned by a node handle: they become usable if the element is inserted into a container.

Between the two, they mean that:

- if an element is retrieved from the map and the element is then extracted (as a node handle), the element is still valid but should only be accessed through the handle.
- if the element is then added to a map (by inserting the node handle), the original element references and pointers from before the extraction can now be safely used, but any pointers or references obtained from the node handle become invalid and should no longer be used.